# Programatically generate view and capture bitmap

Tags: android, view, bitmap

I'm programmatically generating a view in Android. The parent view is a `RelativeLayout` and I'm adding subviews dynamically (e.g. `TextView` and `ImageView`).

If I add the view to my activity's main view then it displays fine (just as expected). Using this code.

```
LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
mainView.addView(dynamicallyGeneratedView);
```

I don't want to add the view as a subview though, I just want to turn it into a bitmap. So I do the following:

```
view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
view.draw(c);
```

But when I add this bitmap to an ImageView it doesn't show anything.

What am I doing wrong? I want to generate a view, turn it into a bitmap but **not** display it on the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you definitely do not have a call to `layout()` after `measure()`, which AFAIK is required here.

Whether you can get away with `View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` and stuff like `getMeasuredWidth()`, I can't say, as I haven't tried that. Whenever I have manually measured and laid out a `View`, I have always used actual sizes, such as:

```
root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add, null);
root.measure(800, 480);
root.layout(0, 0, 800, 480);
```

If your `Bitmap` presently has a useful size, but just does not have any content, try `layout()` with the size before you draw to the `Canvas`. If your `Bitmap` wound up with some less-than-useful size (e.g., one or both dimensions are 0), you will probably need to specify an actual size rather than go `UNSPECIFIED`.

Comment: Ok so that worked somewhat, thank you (I can see an image now) but unfortunately its not laying out the subviews in the bitmap the same as when I add the view as a subview directly. Is there a way to make the view think its being added as a subview to the activity view without actually adding it?

Comment: @ThomasClayson: Not that I am aware of. Having a root of `RelativeLayout`, though, is probably your problem. Try wrapping it in something else (e.g., `FrameLayout`) or switching to a different container class than `RelativeLayout`. `RelativeLayout` only works if it knows its parent, and in your case, it has no parent.

Comment: Perfect. I added an extra FrameLayout as the parent view to my RelativeLayout and it is working now! Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThomasClayson: Glad to hear that it is working! If you don't mind my asking, were you able to keep `UNSPECIFIED`, or did you have to hard-code a size?

Comment: I hardcoded a size. I did the fixed width and set the height to 999 which (to be honest) has no bearing on the actual size it ends up as.