# High level 2D drawing API that supports layouts

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to draw text and basic shapes to a bitmap but using an API that has a higher level of support for layouts. You could think of this as converting Android xml layouts to bitmaps instead of views. Better yet, having an API like Jetpack Compose that renders to a bitmap instead of a view.

The 2D drawing API built into Android and used by the Canvas object is rather low level, since I would need to handle a lot of calculations concerning the x,y locations and size of things drawn. Drawing a table for instance with several rows and columns filled in with text would be considered a high level API. Defining this in some sort of markup or done through an API like Jetpack Compose would be ideal.

If there was a way to get Jetpack Compose to render to a bitmap, that would be the ultimate solution.

I haven't been able to find anything on Github and nothing with Google search.

Comment: "You could think of this as converting Android xml layouts to bitmaps instead of views" -- that is [not hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27090394/115145). "If there was a way to get Jetpack Compose to render to a bitmap, that would be the ultimate solution" -- in the end, the `ComposeView` is rendering to a `Canvas`. It should work to do the same thing as in the linked answer, though I have not tried it in a year or so. Also, in both cases, anything done purely by the GPU (e.g., shadows) will not be covered.